# SQL Query perform slow with increasing users

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2014-express

I have an asp.net web application with SQL server 2014 express database. My application runs well until data entry records are less, but as the data entry records saving increases, not every time but sometime page takes too long to load back again. On save button, after insert/update query is executed, I have reloaded the page to get fresh data. The page takes 2-3 min to load and then it again starts running normally and there is no load. This happens at any time but not everytime. I kept a watch on Activity Monitor, the Processes peaks are high. It show recent expensive query, but that query hardly takes 1 second to run because every time it will have max 120 rows output. I have added all missing indexes, but no success since my query is already optimized. What could be the cause?

Comment: You need to add some code so we can see what could be causing the problem.

Comment: Parameter sniffing issues?